# docker container exec -i [container_name] stat -c '%a' /path

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I got this code from a comrade, but I don't even know what means the "stat -c '%a'"

I looked throught google and on the man of docker but nothing clear

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
commandDocker=$(docker exec -i name)
filepermissions=$(docker exec -i name stat -c '%a' /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.pem)
$commandDocker mkdir /var/www/certificate
```

No error, but I've to update the work's wiki with some code and explain it. And I don't know what does that mean :/

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out. It's to see the permissions in a format "-c" in octal "'%a'"